# nginx+uwsgi+django emperor mode not working

Tags: python, angularjs, django, nginx, uwsgi

I am doing multi-application nginx+uwsgi setup in django. I am following this [documentation](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html) 
to set up emperor mode for my project.
It works fine when I run "uwsgi --ini myproject_uwsgi.ini" but I am not able to deploy emperor mode following this documentation.
I have researched many docs but not able to find relevant information related to emperor mode setup.
 My nginx.conf file:(angularJS frontend)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 192.168.xx.xx;
    root /home/user/Myspace/workspace/Myproject_frontend/dist;
}
```

My "etc/uwsgi/vassals/uwsgi.ini" file looks like:

```
[uwsgi]

#Django-related settings
#Django's wsgi file
wsgi-file = /home/user/Myspace/workspace/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py
http = 192.168.xx.xx:8080
virtualenv = /home/user/Myspace/VENV_MYPROD
```

Also, i have created a uwsgi.service file in "/etc/systemd/system/uwsgi.service" to start emperor mode service and it looks like:

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI Emperor service
After=syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals/
RuntimeDirectory= uwsgi
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
StandardError=syslog
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Please provide help on setting up uwsgi emperor mode.